# How to add autolayout for - a label inside each segment in segment control

Tags: ios

I am using segment control with Auto layout. I have two segments namely 'Group Stock' and 'My Stock'. And I need to show the total count of each stock inside the segment . i.e each segment will contain a label showing the total count. So how to add auto layout for this label inside each segment??

Comment: If you correctly specify constraints for your segment, it will automatically grow/shrink depending on its contents.

Comment: But how to centre that totalCount label inside each segment using auto layout ??

Comment: `UISegementedControl` already has labels in it. You can access them using `segment.titleForSegmentAtIndex:`. If you want to change text in specific segement use `segment.setTitle(text, forSelectedSegementIndex:index)`.

Comment: In my segment control I have added a segment title as "GroupStock", Now I want to add a count label below that segment which refers the "GroupStock count", so how to add that label so that it appears to be at the centre of that segment using auto layout ?

Answer (score 0):

Set your segmented control `Auto-Size Mode` to `Equal Widths`, then add next constraints for your count label:

- Vertical space to your segment (e.g. 8 points below segment).
- Center horizontally to your segment (let it 0 points for a moment).

Create and connect an `IBOutlet` for center constraint, like that:

```
  @IBOutlet weak var labelCenterConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

And then in `viewDidLoad`, and every time you'd like to change `countLabel` text or text on your segmented control call:

```
   labelCenterConstraint.constant = -segment.frame.width/4
   view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

What it does exactly:

- It calculates center of second segment.
- Calls `layoutIfNeeded` to layout your count label.

Here's screenshot.
[image]